# Is it possible to just update Rails form input field value using turbo frames?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview, actionviewhelper

Let's say I have a form built with Rails form builder. It has a text field, and I want to dynamically update the input field's value using AJAX and turbo streams.

Is it possible to update the same text field's value without replacing it with a newly created text field using the `text_field` helper from the turbo stream view?

This [Gorails tutorial](https://gorails.com/episodes/dynamic-select-fields-with-rails-hotwire?autoplay=1) has a similar use case, but he is updating the values of a select tag. So, he just updated the options of the select tag using `options_for_select` helper so the select field remains on the DOM as it is, while only the options are replaced.

Comment: I'm curious why updating the field, vs. just the contents, is unacceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way to do this, but making custom turbo stream actions is very easy:

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

Turbo.StreamActions.update_input = function () {
  this.targetElements.forEach((target) => {
    target.value = this.templateContent.textContent
  });
};
```

```rb
# app/views/users/_form.html.erb

<%= form_with model: @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

```rb
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb

def update
  helpers.fields model: @user do |f|
    render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.action(
     :update_input, f.field_id(:name), "new value"
    )
  end
end
```

*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/streams#custom-actions*

If you need another example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76112894/207090

Comment: Wow! that's a nice approach. Thanks a lot.